# Where And clause entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

i would select on multiple conditions

i know that i can select using this statement

```
    var session = (from us in context.UserSessions
               where us.UserId == dbUser.Id
               select us).FirstOrDefault();
```

but i would like to do something like this

```
    var session = (from us in context.UserSessions
               where us.UserId == dbUser.Id
               and us.somefield == somevalue
               select us).FirstOrDefault();
```

but the and keyword is not recognised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't let the query syntax fool you :) - it's C#, so `and` is still `&&`:

```
var session = (from us in context.UserSessions
           where us.UserId == dbUser.Id
           && us.somefield == somevalue
           select us).FirstOrDefault();
```

Alternatively, this can be more succinctly expressed in Lambda syntax (and you can drop the redundant `Select` and `Where` clauses if you use the [`FirstOrDefault` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx) which takes a predicate):

```
var session = context
       .UserSessions
       .FirstOrDefault(us => us.UserId == dbUser.Id && us.somefield == somevalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var session = (from us in context.UserSessions
               where us.UserId == dbUser.Id
               && us.somefield == somevalue
               select us).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally discouraged.  Please explain your answer.